# CSS style not work in asp.net Button

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i want to make a login page, and i find a template from [HERE](http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/dark-login-form/demo).

[My sample in here.](http://nickydemo.azurewebsites.net/loginstyle/Login.aspx)

When i replace the login `<button>` to `<asp:Button>`, the css style look like not being applied with this, why? And how to fix it?

There is my html code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="nickydemo.loginstyle.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Dark Login Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <%--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="login">
        <p>
            <label for="login">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="name@example.com"/>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="4815162342"/>
        </p>

        <p class="login-submit">
            <%--<button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>--%>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="login-button" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        </p>

        <p class="forgot-password"><a href="index.html">Forgot your password?</a></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just give it a class and apply the styles to that class

Comment: @odedta - please read the code before commenting.  You can see that the OP has already done that using `login-button`

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason why the `login-button` styling wouldn't be implemented.  Have you checked the rendered HTML, to make sure the browser is receiving `class="login-button"`?

Comment: Hi @freefaller, i checked it work by using html <button>, there is sample:
http://nickydemo.azurewebsites.net/loginstyle/LoginWithHtmlButton.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the HTML of the example you provided is different than the one you created.

Example:

```
<p class="login-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Login" id="Button1" class="login-button">
</p>
```

Yours:

```
<p class="login-submit">
  <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
</p>
```

The example uses the :before and :after of the button to get the blue background, which the input does not have. So either you have to force it to be a button, or you can create a div or some other element around your input to get this result.

Edit:

Try this:

```
<div class="login-submit">
    <div class="login-button">
        <input type="submit" class=""></input>
    </div>    
</div>
```

and change the padding of .login-button (line 213 of style.css) to padding: 0px;

Second edit:
Delete the part of the .login-button:before (line 232 of style.css) and add the following:

```
input#Button1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background: #00a2d3;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00a2d3, #0d7796);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00a2d3, #0d7796);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00a2d3, #0d7796);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00a2d3, #0d7796);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #00a2d3, 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #00a2d3, 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 38px;
    display: block;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Douwe de Haan, i think you're right, but i have no idea how to force it to be a button or create a div or some other element around my input.
Can you give me some sample?
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @NickyLiu I added the code. I tried it at your example, I think this will work.

Comment: Hi @Douwe de Haan, i tried your code, it look like this:
http://nickydemo.azurewebsites.net/loginstyle/s1.aspx

Comment: @NickyLiu I changed the code and double checked it. See the change from p to div (.login-sumit) and the CSS change

Comment: Hi @Douwe de Haan, i found another problem, when i input password, and press 'TAB' to focus login button, css style will disappear.
http://nickydemo.azurewebsites.net/loginstyle/s1.aspx

Comment: Hi @Douwe de Haan, the extra edit have fixed the 'TAB' problem, but arrow icon disappear. Please see:
http://nickydemo.azurewebsites.net/loginstyle/s1.aspx

Comment: @NickyLiu I'm not able to check, because I don't have a computer with me right now, but could the problem be in the z-index?

Answer (score 2):

**:before and :after render inside a container**

> Pseudo-elements can only be defined (or better said are only
>   supported) on container elements. Because the way they are rendered
>   are within the container itself as a child element. **input can not
>   contain other elements hence they're not supported. A button on the
>   other hand that's also a form element supports them**, because it's a
>   container of other sub-elements.

Refer this **[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is rooted in difference between `input` and `button`, specifically regarding how CSS pseudo-elements behave.

Here is a jsfiddle showing how the `:before` pseudo-element behaves differently across two seemingly identical elements.

The `:before` is applied to the `button`, but not the `input`.

https://jsfiddle.net/qcspe9qm/

I would suggest just leaving your HTML button in place and `onclick`:

```
<button onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" >Login</button>
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to your ASP.NET Button and then apply the desired style to it.

```
<asp:Button class="mybtn" Text="Button" runat="server"></asp:Button>

.mybtn
{
   border:1px solid Red;
   //some more styles
}
```

EDIT: Try using `display: none` or `!important` for that class to see if it has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The webforms ASP.net Button is creating the button using:

```
<input type="submit">
```

your given example the button is rendered using:

```
 <button type="submit">.
```

They will function the same, but I suspect that there's CSS targeting button instead of input and that's the problem.

How does it look if you comment out the ASP.net button and add in the button using the  tag?

Comment: It is not a button they target, but the before and after pseudo elements.

Comment: Hi @John MC, this is result for using html <button>
http://nickydemo.azurewebsites.net/loginstyle/LoginWithHtmlButton.aspx